# Open another cmd script from a cmd script without opening a new window

Tags: windows, cmd, command-prompt

I'm trying to open a command script, say command1.cmd, from command.cmd, but I want to do this without opening a new console window. I tried `start command1.cmd`, but it opens a new window. Please can someone tell me how to do this.

Comment: Don't use `start`. `Start` starts programs in unusual ways.

Answer (score 0):

Use `call` or if you're not need to return back to the first script just call the second script directly by its name.

> Calls one batch program from another.
>
> CALL [drive:][path]filename [batch-parameters]
>
> batch-parameters   Specifies any command-line information required
>   by the
>                        batch program.

Comment: If you're happy with the answer then please [accept it as a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).